# "convert.im6: memory allocation failed `a.svg'", trying to convert a 691 KB SVG file to EPS with 100 GB of RAM

Tags: memory, conversion, ubuntu-14.04, imagemagick

I tried to convert a 691 KB SVG file into EPS with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg) using the command `convert a.svg a.eps`, but I get a `memory allocation failed` error message:

```
ubuntu@server:~$ convert a.svg a.eps
convert.im6: memory allocation failed `a.svg' @ error/svg.c/ReadSVGImage/2889.
convert.im6: no images defined `a.eps' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

My computer runs Ubuntu 14.04 x64 and has 100 GB of RAM. Nothing else is running on it.

What could be the issue? The file is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4y6Mj_UZoTEWlJPU2hNam9VUmc/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Dude....100GB of RAM? Ya sure?

Comment: @Grumpyol'bear 99007376 KiB of RAM to be precise. Apparently, that's not enough…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ImageMagick is the tool you want to use when you want to convert a SVG to EPS. Both formats are vector formats but ImageMagick will convert the SVG file to a raster image.

The reason that your conversion fails is because your image has a ridiculous large canvas. The width and height are 216000pt which is 288000 pixels according to some online converters. Lets assume you are using Q8 version of ImageMagick. To convert the vector image into a raster image you will need the following number of bits: `288000 (width) * 288000 (height) * 8 (bits per channel) * 3 (number of channels) = 1.990656e+12` which is `248.8 GB`. And that is why ImageMagick is unable to allocate your image. When you are using the Q16 version of ImageMagick you will need twice that amount of memory

If you still want to convert the image even though you probably need another tool you can limit the size of your image with the -density option. The following command will create a PNG that is 1200x1200 for your image:

`convert -density 6 a.svg a.png`